# ClassNotFoundException - when running ant-junit

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, ant-junit

I'm trying to create a Proof of concept for the actual application, The task is to run ant-junit tests without adding stuff to the global environment. I've achieved it so far in ant, but, I'm stuck with the following exception. ClassTest.java is the java class that has sample unit testcase. (Junit 3.0  style). I'm not sure why ant-junit does not find the class inspite of mentioning the paths in the batchrun task.

**project structure**

[image]

I get the following exception when running ant-junit task.

```
Testsuite: ClassTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec

    Caused an ERROR
ClassTest
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ClassTest
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseSingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseSingleCheckExecutor.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)
```

My ant build.xml file is

```
<project name="Java project build" default="build">
<property name="project.local.directory" value="C:\Users\usrpao\workspace\Ant" />
<property name="src.path" value="${project.local.directory}/src" />
<property name="lib.path" value="${project.local.directory}/lib" />
<property name="dest.path" value="${project.local.directory}/target" />
<property name="junit.output.dir" value="${project.local.directory}/junit" />

<path id="classpath.test">
    <fileset dir="lib">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<!--<taskdef name="junit" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask">
    <classpath refid="classpath.test" />
</taskdef> -->

<path id="MyProject.classpath">
    <pathelement location="lib/ant-junit.jar" />
    <pathelement location="lib/junit.jar" />
        <pathelement location="bin/*.*"/>
</path>

<path id="lib.classpath">
    <pathelement location="lib/ant-junit.jar" />
    <pathelement location="lib/junit.jar" />
</path>

<target name="build" depends="clean">
    <javac srcdir="${src.path}" destdir="${dest.path}" classpathref="lib.classpath">
    </javac>
    <antcall target="test">
    </antcall>
</target>

<target name="clean">

</target>

<target name="test">
    <pathconvert property="testoutput" refid="classpath.test" />
    <echo>Path = ${testoutput}</echo>
    <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}" />
    <junit haltonerror="false" showoutput="true">

        <classpath refid="MyProject.classpath">
        </classpath>
        <batchtest todir="${junit.output.dir}">
            <formatter type="plain" />
            <fileset dir="${src.path}/com/ant/test">
                <include name="**/*Test*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </batchtest>

    </junit>
</target>
```

Comment: Why are you including `<pathelement location="bin/*.*"/>` in `MyProject.classpath`? Shouldn't it be `<pathelement location="${dest.path}"/>` instead?

Comment: @manouti that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classpath is referencing the `bin` directory while the classes are actually under the `target` directory. You should change the `MyProject.classpath` reference to include `${project.local.directory}/target`:

```
<path id="MyProject.classpath">
   <pathelement location="lib/ant-junit.jar" />
   <pathelement location="lib/junit.jar" />
   <dirset dir="${project.local.directory}">
        <include name="target"/>
    </dirset>
</path>
```

In addition, you should change the `fileset` element inside the `junit` task by removing the folders corresponding to the package name of the test class, otherwise you will still get a `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
<junit haltonerror="false" showoutput="true">

    <classpath refid="MyProject.classpath">
    </classpath>
    <batchtest todir="${junit.output.dir}">
        <formatter type="plain" />
        <fileset dir="${src.path}">  <!-- remove com/ant/test corresponding to package name -->
            <include name="**/*Test*.java" />
        </fileset>
    </batchtest>

</junit>
```

Comment: could you please take a look at the issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24915142/classnotfoundexception-when-running-ant-junit

Answer (score 0):

From your folder structure it is evident that the class `ClassTest.class` is in `target` folder. so in `class-path` you should include following:

```
<pathelement path="target"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That did not work, i put the folder in the <path id="MyProject.classpath">
  <pathelement location="lib/ant-junit.jar" />
  <pathelement location="lib/junit.jar" />
  <pathelement path="target" />
 </path> path classpath element, did not work.