# ClassNotFoundException when running ant junit

Tags: java, ant, junit

I'm running into this `ClassNotFoundException` issue when running **Junit** task below, but this is non eclipse based project running an ant build from command prompt, the build file is pasted below. The exception is below. I have done similar to that of setup [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830303/classnotfoundexception-when-running-ant-junit) it does not work though, any pointers will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
Class org.apache.tools.ant.util.StringUtils loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
    [junit] Testsuite: SampleTest
Class org.apache.tools.ant.util.FileUtils loaded from parent loader (parentFirst)
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
    [junit] 
    [junit]     Caused an ERROR
    [junit] SampleTest
    [junit] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SampleTest
    [junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:235)
    [junit]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:302)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:219)
    [junit]
```

[image: Project Structure]

**Build.xml**

```
<project name="Java project build" default="test">
    <property name="project.local.directory" value="." />
    <property name="src.path" value="${project.local.directory}/SampleUnitTest/com" />
    <property name="lib.path" value="${project.local.directory}/APP-INF/lib" />
    <property name="dest.path" value="${project.local.directory}/SampleUnitTest/target" />
    <property name="junit.output.dir" value="${project.local.directory}/junit" />

    <path id="MyProject.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${lib.path}/ant-junit.jar" />
        <pathelement location="${lib.path}/junit.jar" />        
        <pathelement location="${lib.path}/SampleUnitTest.jar" />           
        <dirset dir="${project.local.directory}/SampleUnitTest">
            <include name="target" />
        </dirset>       
    </path>
    <path id="lib.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${lib.path}/ant-junit.jar" />
        <pathelement location="${lib.path}/junit.jar" />
        <fileset dir="${lib.path}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <target name="test" description="Tests the java files" depends="build">
        <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}" />
        <junit>
            <classpath refid="MyProject.classpath">
            </classpath>
            <batchtest todir="${junit.output.dir}">
                <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
                <fileset dir="${src.path}">
                    <include name="**/*Test*.java" />
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </target>

    <target name="build" description="Tests the java files" depends="clean">
        <mkdir dir="${dest.path}" />
        <javac srcdir="${src.path}" destdir="${dest.path}" classpathref="lib.classpath">
        </javac>        
        <jar destfile="${lib.path}/SampleUnitTest.jar" basedir="${dest.path}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean" description="Tests the java files">
        <delete dir="${dest.path}">
        </delete>
    </target>
</project>
```

---

**Update**

```
package com; 

import com.tds.metasolv.common.util.CommonUtilities;
import com.tds.metasolv.common.util.specific.PortAddressUtilities;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class SampleTest extends TestCase
{ 
    PortAddressUtilities utils = null;

    protected void setUp() throws Exception{
        utils = PortAddressUtilities.getInstance(CommonUtilities.getInstance());
    }

    public void testGetPONPortNumber(){
        String result = utils.getPONPortNumber("N10-1-2-3-4");
        assertTrue("Expected 3, but got "+result +" in the result. ", result.equals("3"));
        result = utils.getPONPortNumber("N10-1-2-3");
        assertTrue("Expected 3, but got "+result +" in the result. ",result.equals("2"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is the `src.dir` you have defined

```
<property name="src.path" value="${project.local.directory}/SampleUnitTest/com"/>
```

The class you have created is in `package com` that means the class will be referenced using `com.SampleTest`

In order to fix this anomaly you need to add a src folder and move your `com/Test.java` to that folder so that the above defined `src.path` will be like

```
<property name="src.path" value="${project.local.directory}/SampleUnitTest/src"/>
```

And also change `MyProject.classpath` in build xml as below

```
<path id="MyProject.classpath">
    <pathelement location="${lib.path}/ant-junit.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${lib.path}/junit.jar" />        
    <pathelement location="${lib.path}/SampleUnitTest.jar" />           
    <pathelement location="${project.local.directory}/SampleUnitTest/target"/>
</path>
```

Comment: Please post SampleTest.java

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. But, I have done it a little different, i made SampleUnitTest as the source folder and deleted everything else from that folder, moved all the build paths a level up.